# AWS VPC name/Modify Java

Tags: java, aws-sdk, amazon-vpc

I'm creating a VPC through Java SDK and I'm able to successfully create. But I'm not able to set the name of the VPC. Here is my code below.

```
CreateVpcRequest newVPC = new CreateVpcRequest().withCidrBlock("10.1.0.0/16");
CreateVpcResult res = ec2.createVpc(newVPC);
```

This creates but I'm not able to set the name of the VPC with the VPC object type

```
             Vpc vpc = new Vpc();
             vpc.setCidrBlock("10.0.0.0/16");

                List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
                Tag newTag = new Tag();
                newTag.setKey("Name");
                newTag.setValue("MyVPC");
                tags.add(newTag);
                vpc.setTags(tags);
```

Nor with the ModifyVpcAttributeRequest, Im not able to see any setname or tag attribute in that.

Any clue or help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the answer. Should use the createtagsrequest api

```
        CreateTagsRequest createTagsRequest = new CreateTagsRequest();
        createTagsRequest.setTags(tags);
        createTagsRequest.withResources(vpcres.getVpc().getVpcId()) ;
        ec2.createTags(createTagsRequest);
```